# Dynamically build lambda expression from a collection of objects?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, linq-to-objects, kendo-ui-mvc

I have a list of sorts stored in this format:

```
public class ReportSort
{
    public ListSortDirection SortDirection { get; set; }
    public string Member { get; set; }
}
```

And I need to turn it into a lambda expression of type `Action<DataSourceSortDescriptorFactory<TModel>>`

So assuming I have the following collection of Report Sorts as:

```
new ReportSort(ListSortDirection.Ascending, "LastName"),
new ReportSort(ListSortDirection.Ascending, "FirstName"),
```

I would need to transform it into such a statement to be used like so:

```
.Sort(sort => { 
        sort.Add("LastName").Ascending();
        sort.Add("FirstName").Ascending();
      })
```

And the sort method signature is:

```
public virtual TDataSourceBuilder Sort(Action<DataSourceSortDescriptorFactory<TModel>> configurator)
```

So I have some method right now:

```
public static Action<DataSourceSortDescriptorFactory<TModel>> ToGridSortsFromReportSorts<TModel>(List<ReportSort> sorts) where TModel : class
    {
        Action<DataSourceSortDescriptorFactory<TModel>> expression;
        //stuff I don't know how to do
        return expression;
    }
```

...and I have no idea what to do here.

EDIT: Answer is:

```
var expression = new Action<DataSourceSortDescriptorFactory<TModel>>(x =>
        {
            foreach (var sort in sorts)
            {
                if (sort.SortDirection == System.ComponentModel.ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                {
                    x.Add(sort.Member).Ascending();
                }
                else
                {
                    x.Add(sort.Member).Descending();
                }
            }
        });
```

I was thinking at first I had to dynamically build a lambda expression from scratch using the Expression class. Luckily that wasn't the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...and I have no idea what to do here.

Well, reason it out.

What have you got in hand? A `List<ReportSort>` called `sorts`.

What do you need? An `Action<Whatever>`.

You've already taken the first step: you've make a method that takes the thing you have and returns the thing you need. Great first step.

```
    Action<DataSourceSortDescriptorFactory<TModel>> expression;
    //stuff I don't know how to do
    return expression;
```

And you've called out what you don't know how to do -- yet.  This is a good technique.

Start by filling in something that compiles but doesn't work properly.

```
Action<DataSourceSortDescriptorFactory<TModel>> expression = 
  sort => {         
    sort.Add("LastName").Ascending();
    sort.Add("FirstName").Ascending();
  };
return expression;
```

Excellent.  **Now you have a compiling program which means you can run your tests and verify that if this case is expected, the test passes, and if anything else is expected, the test fails.**

Now think, what have I got in hand?  I've got a list of stuff, and I'm doing an `Action`.  That means that a side effect is happening, probably involving every item on the list.  So there's probably a `foreach` in there somewhere:

```
Action<DataSourceSortDescriptorFactory<TModel>> expression = 
  sort => {         
    sort.Add("LastName").Ascending();
    sort.Add("FirstName").Ascending();
    foreach(var sort in sorts) { 
      // Do something
    }
  };
return expression;
```

Compile it.  It fails.  Ah, we have confused the sort we are adding to with the new sort we are adding.  Fix the problem.

```
Action<DataSourceSortDescriptorFactory<TModel>> expression = 
  existingSort => {         
    existingSort.Add("LastName").Ascending();
    existingSort.Add("FirstName").Ascending();
    foreach(var newSort in sorts) { 
      // Do something
    }
  };
return expression;
```

Great, now again we are in a position to compile and run tests.

The pattern here should be clear.  **Keep it compiling, keep running tests, gradually make your program more and more correct, reason about the operations you can perform on the values that you have in hand.**

Can you finish it off?

Comment: Yeah I was able to figure it out, thanks for posting a detailed answer. I thought I would have to manually build a lambda expression from scratch, which is where I get dizzy trying to understand it, this wasn't as hard as I feared.

Comment: @SventoryMang: It *is* possible to build a lambda entirely from scratch and compile it, using a variety of techniques. But it is usually not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following lambda expression that you could assign to the `Action<T>` delegate. In that lambda expression, capture the `List<T>` variable and loop over it:

```
public static Action<DataSourceSortDescriptorFactory<TModel>> ToGridSortsFromReportSorts<TModel>(List<ReportSort> sorts) where TModel : class
{
    Action<DataSourceSortDescriptorFactory<TModel>> expression = 
       result  => 
       {
           foreach (var sort in sorts)
           {
                if (sort.SortDirection == ListSortDirection.Ascending)
                    result.Add(sort.Member).Ascending();
                else // or whatever other methods you want to handle here
                    result.Add(sort.Member).Descending();
           }
       };
    return expression;
}
```

Comment: Note that `delegate (T t) { ... }` is poor style in code written after C# 3 shipped. Instead use `(T t) => { ... }`

Comment: @EricLippert yeah idk why i wrote that. fixed